# PHP / Mongo: Persistable models don't unserialize

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, casting

I'm trying to to use a Persistable model as value in a Mongo document
The Persistable class looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Media\Models;

use MongoDB\BSON\Persistable;

class MediaUid implements Persistable
{

    public readonly string $val;

    public function __construct(string $val)
    {
        $this->val = $val;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->val;
    }

    public function bsonSerialize()
    {
        return ['val' => $this->val];
    }

    public function bsonUnserialize(array $data)
    {
        $this->val = $data['val'];
    }

}
```

I have a model like

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Collection\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class SomeModel extends Model
{

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

}
```

And I save the model like this:

```
$test = new SomeModel();
$test->someId = new ObjectId();
$test->someMedia = new MediaUid('1234567890');
$test->save();
```

The serialization goes perfect and the document looks like this:

```
$t = SomeModel::find($test->id);
print_r(json_decode($t->__toString())); // Prints:
// stdClass Object
// (
//     [_id] => 64e08963b7b5fab0a10573c3
//     [someId] => 64e08963b7b5fab0a10573c2
//     [someMedia] => stdClass Object
//         (
//             [__pclass] => stdClass Object
//                 (
//                     [$binary] => RG9tYWluXEZpbGVcTW9kZWxzXE1lZGlhVXVpZA==
//                     [$type] => 80
//                 )
//
//             [val] => 1234567890
//         )
//
//     [updated_at] => 2023-08-19T09:20:35.073000Z
//     [created_at] => 2023-08-19T09:20:35.073000Z
// )
```

When I read the individual values the `someId` is now an MongoDB\BSON\ObjectIdArray (as it should be) but the `someMedia` is still an ordinary array instead of a MediaUid

```
print_r(get_class($t->someId) . PHP_EOL); // Prints: MongoDB\BSON\ObjectIdArray
print_r(gettype($t->someMedia) . PHP_EOL); // Prints: array
```

There are very few examples of how a Persistable class is supposed to work so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or just missing something?

I'm using Laravel so maybe the way it has something to do with the way it's retrieving the document?

If the `bsonUnserialize` is not supposed to work like this then I'd like to know what the proper way should be.

PS In my actual code these id's are used all over the place (and sometimes deeply nested) so manually cast them to MediaUid's would be far from ideal.

Used versions:

- PHP v8.2
- Laravel v10.0
- Monogo: 6.0
- jenssegers/mongodb `dev-master`

Comment: You ask about the method call of Collection::find(), but you miss to show Collection in your question. We could now assume what kind of Laravel magic that is, however often its changed, so it would lead to speculation. Apart from that just by the generic name I'd assume it has no information about concrete types and as there is no reviver shown, it looks perfectly normal you have a structure of arrays there. So the reasoning is less with retrieving the document - that works according to what you write - but with reviving it.

Comment: @hakre I improved the example so hopefully it's a bit cleaner and clearer now. SomeModel is completely empty with no magic other than what Laravel does with it :)

Comment: I've looked a bit yesterday and I think it is useful for the dedicated Laravel developer to learn about how you managed it to convince Eloquent to work with a MongoDB server. That's a library you required with Composer, right? Then for clarity, name it as this is at least giving good context information. Also showing MongoDB versions (server + PHP client) , PHP version. As you're asking about one system (PHP) talking to another (MongoDB) at the end of the day. And if you then already know if that library that you use is based on PDO or something else, I think could also be helpful to know.

Comment: Thanks, I added the versions. I know how to use Eloquent to cast for example `someMedia` in case of my given example. However like is said in my actual code the id's are deeply nested and it's not really feasible to cast them the regular way (would be too much to explain why exactly). If no one has a descent solution I'm afraid I have to do the casting manually :(